# converting instagram location id to latitude and longitude so that I can overlay them on Google Map

Tags: json, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude, instagram-api

I have JSON files for Instagram posts that look like the following with respect to location:

> "location":{"id":"794643567398395","has_public_page":true,"name":"Madison Square Garden","slug":"madison-square-garden","address_json":"{\"street_address\": \"\", \"zip_code\": \"10001\", \"city_name\": \"New York, New York\", \"region_name\": \"\", \"country_code\": \"US\", \"exact_city_match\": false, \"exact_region_match\": false, \"exact_country_match\": false}"}

Here, how can I convert this location ID to a latitude/longitude such that it could be overlayed on the Google Map?

The above is taken for the JSON for this post: https://www.instagram.com/p/B1xEDA0llSq/

Answer (score 1):

#### You can use the `instagram_private_api` python library to find the latitude and longitude of any Instagram or facebook (I mean META) location id.

```
pip install instagram-private-api
```

```py
from instagram_private_api import Client
USERNAME = 'YOUR_INSTAGRAM_USERNAME'
PASSWORD = 'YOUR_INSTAGRAM_PASSWORD'
location_id = 794643567398395


api = Client(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

api.location_info(location_id)
```

#### Output:

```json
{'location': {'pk': 794643567398395,
  'short_name': 'Madison Square Garden',
  'facebook_places_id': 794643567398395,
  'external_source': 'facebook_places',
  'name': 'Madison Square Garden',
  'address': '4 Pennsylvania Plaza',
  'city': 'New York, New York',
  'has_viewer_saved': None,
  'lng': -73.993499279022,
  'lat': 40.75050203785},
 'status': 'ok'}
```

for more information about the library read [here](https://pypi.org/project/instagram-private-api/)

Answer (score 0):

I did this via an external Geocode API. you send either the slug name or location name and you get back a json which includes the long and lat. 
you need to get your own api_key.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import ssl

api_key = your_own_api_key

serviceurl = 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?'

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE


address = input('Enter location: ')

parms = dict()
parms['key'] = api_key
parms['location'] = address    
url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode(parms)

print('Retrieving', url)
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
data = uh.read().decode()
print('Retrieved', len(data), 'characters')

try:
    js = json.loads(data)
except:
    js = None

#print(json.dumps(js, indent=4))

lat = js['results'][0]['locations'][0]['latLng']['lat']
lng = js['results'][0]['locations'][0]['latLng']['lng']
print('lat,lng', str(lat) +','+ str(lng))
```