# How can I pull any kind of geospatial data based on location id from the instagram api?

Tags: api, geolocation, instagram-api

I'm pretty new to the instagram API so apologies if this is a dumb question. I'm trying to extract some measure of location (ideally latitude and longitude) from a list of ~250 location ids that I pulled from instagram. The closest thing I can find to my question is this [converting instagram location id to latitude and longitude so that I can overlay them on Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703736/converting-instagram-location-id-to-latitude-and-longitude-so-that-i-can-overlay) except I don't have the address.

I've read the documentation and I suspect the url request should be structured as below, which I found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location/

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/{location-id}&access_token={user-access-token}
```

But I can't seem to return any results. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I can share a reliable alternative to the official Instagram API with good support.
To get geodata based on location id, you need to create several queries:

POST request to download geodata:

[https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/location/{location_id}/update?access_token=YOUR](https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/location/%7Blocation_id%7D/update?access_token=YOUR) TOKEN

GET request to check the task status:

[https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/location/{location_id}/update?access_token=YOUR](https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/location/%7Blocation_id%7D/update?access_token=YOUR) TOKEN

GET request to get geodata:

[https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/location/{location_id}?access_token=YOUR](https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/location/%7Blocation_id%7D?access_token=YOUR) TOKEN

You can see at this [link](https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/docs#tag/Instagram-location-search/paths/%7E1instagram%7E1location%7E1%7Blocation_id%7D/get) what location data you will receive.

For this service, getting geodata is a part of finding posts by location task.

But if you do not specify any additional parameters in the request, you will receive data only by location as a result.